# AddBody for RestSharp is failing when serializing to JSON

Tags: c#

I am trying to do AddBody for a restrequest post method. I am using RestSharp version 104.XXX which doesnt have addJsonBody like version 105.XXXX has because of other issues that my application faces. So I am stuck with version 104 and in the process I cannot use addBody and send a serialized json and everytime i use the below code, I get . "error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"Content type 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8' not supported".. Has anyone came across this issue and figured out a way using old version of RestSharp..

```
  var restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
  restRequest.AddHeader("authorization",  "Bearer " + token);
  restRequest.AddHeader("source", "M");
  restRequest.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
  restRequest.AddBody(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestObj, this.jsonSettings));
```

Comment: Try `restRequest.AddParameter("application/json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestObj, this.jsonSettings), ParameterType.RequestBody);` and see if that does anything different.

Comment: @dvo Awesome Thank you.. Quickly add than as an answer so I can accept as a correct one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify that the body parameter is JSON by doing the following:

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", jsonString, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Your case:

```
restRequest.AddParameter("application/json", 
                         JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestObj, this.jsonSettings), 
                         ParameterType.RequestBody);
```